# Does single core speed benefit from a huge L3 cache?

Tags: x86-64, intel, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache, amd-processor

Let's say I have a CPU with 32 cores and a huge 120 MB L3 cache. If I run some memory-heavy code which executes on only one core, can that single core benefit from the whole L3 cache? As far as I know L3 is shared between cores in most of the modern x86 CPUs...

So I'd say yes, it benefits from it, but I am not sure...this would imply that having many core CPUs with huge L3 caches would in fact speed up single core execution for some memory heavy workloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On an AMD Zen, no, each CCX (core cluster) of 4 cores has its own private L3 that's independent of L3 in other CCXs.

On an Intel CPU, yes.  L3 is shared by all cores in a socket/package.  Having a lot of cores each with their own slice of L3 will mean a larger ring-bus or mesh, and higher *latency* for L3, but better capacity.

If 8MiB of L3 was enough for most of the accesses from some single-threaded program, it would probably run faster on a quad-core "client" i7 chip than a big Xeon with 32 cores, assuming both ran at the same clock speed.  related: [Why is Skylake so much better than Broadwell-E for single-threaded memory throughput?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39260020/why-is-skylake-so-much-better-than-broadwell-e-for-single-threaded-memory-throug)