# Cache misses when accessing an array in nested loop

Tags: c, performance, caching, cpu-cache, cache-locality

So I have this question from my professor, and I can not figure out why `vector2` is faster and has less cache misses than `vector1`.

Assume that the code below is a valid compilable C code.

**Vector2:**

```
void incrementVector2(INT4* v, int n) {
     for (int k = 0; k < 100; ++k) {
          for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
               v[i] = v[i] + 1;
          }
     }
}
```

**Vector1:**

```
void incrementVector1(INT4* v, int n) {
     for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
          for (int k = 0; k < 100; ++k) {
               v[i] = v[i] + 1;
          }
     }
}
```

**NOTE:** INT4 means the integer is 4 Bytes in size.

In terms of CPU specs: cache size = 12288KB, line size=64B and only considering this single cache interacting with main memory.

**Question**

Why does `vector2` have a faster runtime than `vector1`? And why `vector1` will have more cache misses than `vector2`?

Me and a few classmates worked on this for a while and couldn't figure it out. We thought it could be due to the fact that `vector2` has better spatial locatlity, since the array is been accessed by the inner loop constantly, while in `vector1`, only one element is accessed at a time?
we are not sure if this is correct, and also not sure how to bring cache lines in to this either.

Comment: You could have used ISO C `int32_t` like a normal person, instead of inventing an alternate INT4 name for it. :/  Also, I assume 12MiB is the L3 cache size; any real-world CPU will have a smaller faster L1d cache, often 32kiB.  (Not to mention a store buffer with store-forwarding, so accessing the same location repeatedly can cause a latency bottleneck...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> We thought it could be due to the fact that vector2 has better spatial
> locatlity, since the array is been accessed by the inner loop
> constantly, while in vector1, only one element is accessed at a time?

Well, both codes have the same accessing pattern, iterating over the array `v` with a stride of 1. Cache spacial-locality-wise both codes are the same. However, the second code:

```
void incrementVector1(INT4* v, int n) {
     for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
          for (int k = 0; k < 100; ++k) {
               v[i] = v[i] + 1;
          }
     }
}
```

Has a better temporal-locality because you access the same element 100 times, whereas in:

```
void incrementVector2(INT4* v, int n) {
     for (int k = 0; k < 100; ++k) {
          for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
               v[i] = v[i] + 1;
          }
     }
}
```

you only access it once on every 'n' iterations.

So either you did a mistake, your teacher is playing some kind of strange game or I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Are you *sure* that you mean that `incrementVector2` is faster?

As *dreamcast* pointed out, `incrementVector1` has better temporal locality, so *it* should be faster.

And, from benchmarks, 1 is faster than 2

50x faster for an array size of 1000.

This is surprising because the array is small enough to become [and stay] cache hot.

And, `incrementVector1` has a much smaller disassembled code size than `incrementVector2` (at `-O3`).

`incrementVector1` is 105 bytes and `incrementVector2` is 203 bytes.

This is somewhat surprising since I would think that although there is some variation, I would not expect such a large discrepancy [See below].

---

Here is the program output:

```
0.000002238 incrementVector1
0.000019535 incrementVector2
8.729x slower

0.000000280 incrementVector1
0.000022454 incrementVector2
80.193x slower

0.000000452 incrementVector1
0.000019617 incrementVector2
43.400x slower

0.000000377 incrementVector1
0.000020632 incrementVector2
54.727x slower

0.000000361 incrementVector1
0.000022612 incrementVector2
62.637x slower
```

---

Here's the program I used:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef long long tsc_t;
typedef int INT4;

tsc_t
tscget(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    tsc_t tsc;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&ts);
    tsc = ts.tv_sec;
    tsc *= 1000000000;
    tsc += ts.tv_nsec;

    return tsc;
}

double
tscsec(tsc_t tsc)
{
    double sec;

    sec = tsc;
    sec /= 1e9;

    return sec;
}

typedef void (*incfnc_p)(INT4 *v, int n);

void
incrementVector2(INT4 *v, int n)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < 100; ++k) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            v[i] = v[i] + 1;
        }
    }
}

void
incrementVector1(INT4 *v, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 100; ++k) {
            v[i] = v[i] + 1;
        }
    }
}

INT4 v[1000] = { 0 };

#define DOFNC(_fnc) \
    dofnc(_fnc,#_fnc)

tsc_t
dofnc(incfnc_p fnc,const char *sym)
{
    tsc_t tscbeg;
    tsc_t tscend;

    tscbeg = tscget();
    fnc(v,sizeof(v) / sizeof(v[0]));
    tscend = tscget();
    tscend -= tscbeg;

    printf("%.9f %s\n",tscsec(tscend),sym);

    return tscend;
}

void
dotest(void)
{
    tsc_t tsc1 = DOFNC(incrementVector1);
    tsc_t tsc2 = DOFNC(incrementVector2);
    double ratio;
    const char *tag;

    if (tsc1 > tsc2) {
        tag = "faster";
        ratio = tsc1;
        ratio /= tsc2;
    }
    else {
        tag = "slower";
        ratio = tsc2;
        ratio /= tsc1;
    }

    printf("%.3fx %s\n",ratio,tag);
}

int
main(void)
{

    for (int testno = 1;  testno <= 5;  ++testno) {
        printf("\n");
        dotest();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is the disassembly:

```
00000000004011c0 <incrementVector2>:
  4011c0:   85 f6                   test   %esi,%esi
  4011c2:   0f 8e be 00 00 00       jle    401286 <L06>
  4011c8:   89 f2                   mov    %esi,%edx
  4011ca:   41 89 f3                mov    %esi,%r11d
  4011cd:   66 0f 6f 0d 8b 0e 00    movdqa 0xe8b(%rip),%xmm1        # 402060 <__dso_handle+0x58>
  4011d4:   00
  4011d5:   49 89 f8                mov    %rdi,%r8
  4011d8:   c1 ea 02                shr    $0x2,%edx
  4011db:   44 8d 56 ff             lea    -0x1(%rsi),%r10d
  4011df:   41 83 e3 fc             and    $0xfffffffc,%r11d
  4011e3:   41 b9 01 00 00 00       mov    $0x1,%r9d
  4011e9:   48 c1 e2 04             shl    $0x4,%rdx
  4011ed:   48 01 fa                add    %rdi,%rdx
  4011f0:L00    41 83 fa 02             cmp    $0x2,%r10d
  4011f4:   0f 86 8d 00 00 00       jbe    401287 <L07>
  4011fa:   48 89 f8                mov    %rdi,%rax
  4011fd:L01    f3 0f 6f 00             movdqu (%rax),%xmm0
  401201:   48 83 c0 10             add    $0x10,%rax
  401205:   66 0f fe c1             paddd  %xmm1,%xmm0
  401209:   0f 11 40 f0             movups %xmm0,-0x10(%rax)
  40120d:   48 39 d0                cmp    %rdx,%rax
  401210:   75 eb                   jne    4011fd <L01>
  401212:   44 89 d8                mov    %r11d,%eax
  401215:   44 39 de                cmp    %r11d,%esi
  401218:   74 22                   je     40123c <L03>
  40121a:L02    48 63 c8                movslq %eax,%rcx
  40121d:   83 04 8f 02             addl   $0x2,(%rdi,%rcx,4)
  401221:   8d 48 01                lea    0x1(%rax),%ecx
  401224:   39 ce                   cmp    %ecx,%esi
  401226:   7e 14                   jle    40123c <L03>
  401228:   48 63 c9                movslq %ecx,%rcx
  40122b:   83 c0 02                add    $0x2,%eax
  40122e:   83 04 8f 02             addl   $0x2,(%rdi,%rcx,4)
  401232:   39 c6                   cmp    %eax,%esi
  401234:   7e 06                   jle    40123c <L03>
  401236:   48 98                   cltq
  401238:   83 04 87 02             addl   $0x2,(%rdi,%rax,4)
  40123c:L03    41 8d 41 01             lea    0x1(%r9),%eax
  401240:   41 83 c1 02             add    $0x2,%r9d
  401244:   41 83 f9 63             cmp    $0x63,%r9d
  401248:   75 a6                   jne    4011f0 <L00>
  40124a:   be 65 00 00 00          mov    $0x65,%esi
  40124f:   4a 8d 7c 97 04          lea    0x4(%rdi,%r10,4),%rdi
  401254:   29 c6                   sub    %eax,%esi
  401256:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    nopw   %cs:0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  40125d:   00 00 00
  401260:L04    41 8b 10                mov    (%r8),%edx
  401263:   8d 42 01                lea    0x1(%rdx),%eax
  401266:   01 f2                   add    %esi,%edx
  401268:   0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  40126f:   00
  401270:L05    89 c1                   mov    %eax,%ecx
  401272:   83 c0 01                add    $0x1,%eax
  401275:   39 d0                   cmp    %edx,%eax
  401277:   75 f7                   jne    401270 <L05>
  401279:   41 89 08                mov    %ecx,(%r8)
  40127c:   49 83 c0 04             add    $0x4,%r8
  401280:   49 39 f8                cmp    %rdi,%r8
  401283:   75 db                   jne    401260 <L04>
  401285:   c3                      retq
  401286:L06    c3                      retq
  401287:L07    31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  401289:   eb 8f                   jmp    40121a <L02>
  40128b:   0f 1f 44 00 00          nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)

0000000000401290 <incrementVector1>:
  401290:   85 f6                   test   %esi,%esi
  401292:   7e 5f                   jle    4012f3 <L02>
  401294:   8d 46 ff                lea    -0x1(%rsi),%eax
  401297:   83 f8 02                cmp    $0x2,%eax
  40129a:   76 59                   jbe    4012f5 <L04>
  40129c:   89 f2                   mov    %esi,%edx
  40129e:   66 0f 6f 0d ca 0d 00    movdqa 0xdca(%rip),%xmm1        # 402070 <__dso_handle+0x68>
  4012a5:   00
  4012a6:   48 89 f8                mov    %rdi,%rax
  4012a9:   c1 ea 02                shr    $0x2,%edx
  4012ac:   48 c1 e2 04             shl    $0x4,%rdx
  4012b0:   48 01 fa                add    %rdi,%rdx
  4012b3:L00    f3 0f 6f 00             movdqu (%rax),%xmm0
  4012b7:   48 83 c0 10             add    $0x10,%rax
  4012bb:   66 0f fe c1             paddd  %xmm1,%xmm0
  4012bf:   0f 11 40 f0             movups %xmm0,-0x10(%rax)
  4012c3:   48 39 d0                cmp    %rdx,%rax
  4012c6:   75 eb                   jne    4012b3 <L00>
  4012c8:   89 f0                   mov    %esi,%eax
  4012ca:   83 e0 fc                and    $0xfffffffc,%eax
  4012cd:   39 f0                   cmp    %esi,%eax
  4012cf:   74 23                   je     4012f4 <L03>
  4012d1:L01    48 63 d0                movslq %eax,%rdx
  4012d4:   83 04 97 64             addl   $0x64,(%rdi,%rdx,4)
  4012d8:   8d 50 01                lea    0x1(%rax),%edx
  4012db:   39 f2                   cmp    %esi,%edx
  4012dd:   7d 14                   jge    4012f3 <L02>
  4012df:   48 63 d2                movslq %edx,%rdx
  4012e2:   83 c0 02                add    $0x2,%eax
  4012e5:   83 04 97 64             addl   $0x64,(%rdi,%rdx,4)
  4012e9:   39 c6                   cmp    %eax,%esi
  4012eb:   7e 06                   jle    4012f3 <L02>
  4012ed:   48 98                   cltq
  4012ef:   83 04 87 64             addl   $0x64,(%rdi,%rax,4)
  4012f3:L02    c3                      retq
  4012f4:L03    c3                      retq
  4012f5:L04    31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  4012f7:   eb d8                   jmp    4012d1 <L01>
  4012f9:   0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax)
```

---

Here is the output of `-S -fverbose-asm`:

```
    .globl  incrementVector2
    .type   incrementVector2, @function
incrementVector2:
.LFB13:
    .cfi_startproc
    testl   %esi, %esi  # n
    jle .L19    #,
    movl    %esi, %edx  # n, bnd.1
    movl    %esi, %r11d # n, niters_vector_mult_vf.2
    movdqa  .LC1(%rip), %xmm1   #, tmp152
    movq    %rdi, %r8   # v, ivtmp.33
    shrl    $2, %edx    #,
    leal    -1(%rsi), %r10d #,
    andl    $-4, %r11d  #, niters_vector_mult_vf.2
# orig.c:38:        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    movl    $1, %r9d    #, ivtmp.47
    salq    $4, %rdx    #, tmp150
    addq    %rdi, %rdx  # v, _144
.L10:
    cmpl    $2, %r10d   #, _72
    jbe .L14    #,
# orig.c:36: {
    movq    %rdi, %rax  # v, ivtmp.36
.L8:
# orig.c:39:            v[i] = v[i] + 1;
    movdqu  (%rax), %xmm0   # MEM[base: _138, offset: 0B], vect__42.13
    addq    $16, %rax   #, ivtmp.36
    paddd   %xmm1, %xmm0    # tmp152, vect__42.13
# orig.c:39:            v[i] = v[i] + 1;
    movups  %xmm0, -16(%rax)    # vect__42.13, MEM[base: _138, offset: 0B]
    cmpq    %rdx, %rax  # _144, ivtmp.36
    jne .L8 #,
# orig.c:38:        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    movl    %r11d, %eax # niters_vector_mult_vf.2, i
    cmpl    %r11d, %esi # niters_vector_mult_vf.2, n
    je  .L9 #,
.L13:
# orig.c:39:            v[i] = v[i] + 1;
    movslq  %eax, %rcx  # i, i
# orig.c:39:            v[i] = v[i] + 1;
    addl    $2, (%rdi,%rcx,4)   #, *_40
# orig.c:38:        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    leal    1(%rax), %ecx   #, i
# orig.c:38:        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    cmpl    %ecx, %esi  # i, n
    jle .L9 #,
# orig.c:39:            v[i] = v[i] + 1;
    movslq  %ecx, %rcx  # i, i
# orig.c:38:        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    addl    $2, %eax    #, i
# orig.c:39:            v[i] = v[i] + 1;
    addl    $2, (%rdi,%rcx,4)   #, *_107
# orig.c:38:        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    cmpl    %eax, %esi  # i, n
    jle .L9 #,
# orig.c:39:            v[i] = v[i] + 1;
    cltq
# orig.c:39:            v[i] = v[i] + 1;
    addl    $2, (%rdi,%rax,4)   #, *_58
.L9:
    leal    1(%r9), %eax    #, _147
    addl    $2, %r9d    #, ivtmp.47
    cmpl    $99, %r9d   #, ivtmp.47
    jne .L10    #,
    movl    $101, %esi  #, tmp147
    leaq    4(%rdi,%r10,4), %rdi    #, _134
    subl    %eax, %esi  # _147, tmp146
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L12:
    movl    (%r8), %edx # MEM[base: _126, offset: 0B], _2
    leal    1(%rdx), %eax   #, ivtmp.21
    addl    %esi, %edx  # tmp146, _122
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L11:
    movl    %eax, %ecx  # ivtmp.21, _25
    addl    $1, %eax    #, ivtmp.21
# orig.c:38:        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    cmpl    %edx, %eax  # _122, ivtmp.21
    jne .L11    #,
    movl    %ecx, (%r8) # _25, MEM[base: _126, offset: 0B]
    addq    $4, %r8 #, ivtmp.33
# orig.c:37:    for (int k = 0; k < 100; ++k) {
    cmpq    %rdi, %r8   # _134, ivtmp.33
    jne .L12    #,
    ret
.L19:
    ret
.L14:
# orig.c:38:        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    xorl    %eax, %eax  # i
    jmp .L13    #
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE13:
    .size   incrementVector2, .-incrementVector2
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  incrementVector1
    .type   incrementVector1, @function
incrementVector1:
.LFB14:
    .cfi_startproc
# orig.c:47:    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    testl   %esi, %esi  # n
    jle .L20    #,
    leal    -1(%rsi), %eax  #, tmp118
    cmpl    $2, %eax    #, tmp118
    jbe .L27    #,
    movl    %esi, %edx  # n, bnd.51
    movdqa  .LC2(%rip), %xmm1   #, tmp131
    movq    %rdi, %rax  # v, ivtmp.62
    shrl    $2, %edx    #,
    salq    $4, %rdx    #, tmp121
    addq    %rdi, %rdx  # v, _58
.L23:
    movdqu  (%rax), %xmm0   # MEM[base: _53, offset: 0B], vect__8.57
    addq    $16, %rax   #, ivtmp.62
    paddd   %xmm1, %xmm0    # tmp131, vect__8.57
    movups  %xmm0, -16(%rax)    # vect__8.57, MEM[base: _53, offset: 0B]
    cmpq    %rdx, %rax  # _58, ivtmp.62
    jne .L23    #,
    movl    %esi, %eax  # n, tmp.53
    andl    $-4, %eax   #, tmp.53
    cmpl    %esi, %eax  # n, tmp.53
    je  .L29    #,
.L22:
# orig.c:49:            v[i] = v[i] + 1;
    movslq  %eax, %rdx  # tmp.53, tmp.53
    addl    $100, (%rdi,%rdx,4) #, *_3
# orig.c:47:    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    leal    1(%rax), %edx   #, i
# orig.c:47:    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    cmpl    %esi, %edx  # n, i
    jge .L20    #,
# orig.c:49:            v[i] = v[i] + 1;
    movslq  %edx, %rdx  # i, i
# orig.c:47:    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    addl    $2, %eax    #, i
    addl    $100, (%rdi,%rdx,4) #, *_47
# orig.c:47:    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    cmpl    %eax, %esi  # i, n
    jle .L20    #,
# orig.c:49:            v[i] = v[i] + 1;
    cltq
    addl    $100, (%rdi,%rax,4) #, *_25
.L20:
# orig.c:52: }
    ret
.L29:
    ret
.L27:
# orig.c:47:    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    xorl    %eax, %eax  # tmp.53
    jmp .L22    #
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE14:
    .size   incrementVector1, .-incrementVector1
    .section    .rodata.str1.1,"aMS",@progbits,1
.LC3:
```

Comment: Actually, I meant temporal locality not spacial xD

Comment: @Craig Estey Yes, that is exactly what the question says given to us by the professor. I will email him to see if he made a mistake with the question.
Thank you for taking your time with testing and showing me the results! :)

Comment: @Pengibaby Yep, it does not sound correct theoretically and Craig have benchmark it as well

Comment: Pretty sure `gcc -O3` is optimizing away the inner loop into `v[i] += 100`, that's why the asm is simpler and machine-code is shorter, and why it's *so* much faster. (And note the branch-target label before the top of the inner loop in vector2).  You didn't show the vector it loads, but I assume it's `.long 1,1,1,1` vs. `.long 100,100,100,100`.  For an array this small (fits in L1d cache), if this optimization wasn't done then vector2 might actually be faster: bottleneck on load/store throughput instead of store-forwarding latency (about ~5 or 6 cycles for 16-byte vectors on modern Intel).

Comment: I think the question has them backwards, but would make sense if we assume large arrays, and that the C is actual pseudo-code for asm, not input to an aggressively optimizing compiler.  (Or e.g. if the pointer is volatile so all accesses actually happen, and happen in source order.  That may defeat auto-vectorization even for vector2 where it would I think be legal even with volatile, except for lack of guarantees about ordering within a 16-byte load or store.)

Comment: Oh yes, the scalar cleanup in vector1 confirms the optimization it's doing: `addl    $100, (%rdi,%rdx,4)`.  Also that there's only one branch to `.L23`, not an inner and outer.  Obviously one pass over the array is going to be faster, and adding 100 costs the same as adding 1.  (If GCC were smarter, vector2 would be subtracting `-1` so it could generate the constant with `pcmpeqd %xmm0,%xmm0` instead of loading it from .rodata, but that's just minor startup overhead :/)

Comment: @PeterCordes Okay, so the optimization makes this _not_ valid as far as OP's premise goes. I always use `-O<whatever` for benchmarking. I can do `-O0`. Is there an `-fno-whatever` option to disable _just_ the "offending" optimization so it's an apples-to-apples test? Or, would making the array pointer `volatile` be fair [enough]? The other thing I could do is replace the literal `100` with a second argument. I routinely add `-fno-inline-*`, so that might do it.

Comment: I'd go for `INT4 = volatile int` with `-O3` because I'm pretty sure I know exactly what that would do to the resulting asm: you'd have scalar `add $1, (mem)` with some loop structure around that.  `-O0` would introduce store-forwarding bottlenecks on the loop counter and thus never let vector2 strut its stuff for small arrays on real-world CPUs.

Comment: So I tried it, but actually GCC is still partially inverting the vector1 loop, doing 2 increments in the inner loop (but each separately, not +=2).  https://godbolt.org/z/rGzxnY (with volatile and repcount=10 instead of 100).  I don't think that's allowed for `volatile`.  Also it's doing separate mov / add / store, so a total of 3 front-end uops instead of 2 per increment.  Anyway, locally with a large array (100000000 elements: ~381 MiB) on i7-6700k at ~3.9GHz with DDR4-2666, I get vector2 about 1.128x slower (for 10 reps, not 100). With 100 reps it's about "2.781x faster" even for large size

Comment: Especially with GCC's partial-inversion, and the very high per-core memory bandwidth available on a "client" chip like my Skylake, HW prefetch can easily keep up with less than one `int` per clock cycle load / store even with L3 cache misses.  Benchmarks on Godbolt are dicey because of load, but it's a Xeon with much lower per-thread memory bandwidth for large arrays.  Of course you have to ignore the first iteration which warms up the array (page faults) and CPU frequency.

Comment: TL:DR: Real-world superscalar OoO exec CPUs with lots of memory-level parallelism aren't as simple a performance model as the OP is probably assuming.  (Probably in-order, fully stall on load miss, and store-forwarding is assumed not to be a bottleneck.  Like a classic RISC with no store buffer and 1-cycle latency L1d cache, although even those CPUs have a load delay due to MEM being a later pipeline stage than exec.  But that hurts equally for reloading a recent store or not.)

Comment: Clang does closer to what I expected, and uses memory-destination add.  https://godbolt.org/z/rEc8h7.  On Godbolt itself, I'm seeing Vector2 1.2x to 1.3x faster for `v[1000000]` and REPCOUNT 10, matching what I see on my desktop for the same.  Vector2 gets some crazy unrolling (of the outer loop I think), repeating the inner loop instead of wrapping it in a repeat.  Unfortunately it uses an indexed addressing mode instead of a pointer increment. :/  The higher the REPCOUNT, the more vector2 wins by.  (e.g. by 4x at 200).

Comment: Of course if we actually count memory bandwidth with `intel_gpu_top -l` (to see true bandwidth including HW prefetch) or if we disabled HW prefetch and looked at perf counters for cache misses, we'd see the expected effects.  Of course, this is all because of volatile stopping the compiler from just keeping the value in a register.  So it's still unrealistic.