# How long does it take to fill a cache line?

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture, latency, cpu-cache

Assuming a cache line is 64 bytes,

100 nanoseconds is the often quoted figure for main memory access, is this figure for 1 byte at a time or for 64 bytes at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's for a whole cache line, of course.

The busses / data-paths along the way are at least 8 bytes wide at every point, with the external DDR bus being the narrowest.  (Possibly also the interconnect between sockets on a multi-core system.)

The "critical word" of the cache line might arrive a cycle or two before the rest of it on some CPUs, maybe even 8 on an ancient Pentium-M, but on many recent CPUs the last step between L2 and L1d is a full 64 bytes wide.  To make best use of that link (for data going either direction), I assume the L2 superqueue waits to receive a full cache line from the 32-byte ring bus on Intel CPUs, for example.

[Skylake](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/microarchitectures/skylake_(client)) for example has 12 Line Fill Buffers, so L1d cache can track cache misses on up to 12 lines in flight at the same time, loads+stores.  And the L2 Superqueue has a few more entries than that, so it can track some additional requests created by hardware prefetching.  Memory-level *parallelism* (as well as prefetching) is very important in mitigating the high latency of cache misses, especially demand loads that miss in L3 and have to go all the way to DRAM.

---

For some actual measurements, see https://www.7-cpu.com/cpu/Skylake.html for example, for Skylake-client i7-6700 with dual-channel DDR4-2400 CL15.

Intel "server" chips, big Xeons, have significantly higher memory latency, enough that it seriously reduces the memory (and L3) bandwidth available to a single core even if the others are idle.  *[Why is Skylake so much better than Broadwell-E for single-threaded memory throughput?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39260020/why-is-skylake-so-much-better-than-broadwell-e-for-single-threaded-memory-throug)*

Although I haven't heard if this has improved much with Ice Lake-server or Sapphire Rapids; it was quite bad when they first switched to a mesh interconnect (and non-inclusive L3) in Skylake-server.

Comment: DDR5 DIMMs have two channels, so the 64-bit data interface is only 32-bits per channel. (This allows a single burst with the new longer length of 16 to provide a 64-byte access.) (I thought High Bandwidth Memory and/or Hybrid Memory Cube used a narrower interface to the processor, but that may be a false memory. I also think HBM used single-direction signalling, which would prefer asymmetric read/write bandwidth. The few pages I looked at only gave information about the internal width and bandwidth.)

Comment: Ice Lake Xeon significantly improves single-threaded memory bandwidth when using streaming stores.  On Cascade Lake Xeon, streaming stores *reduce* single-thread STREAM Copy & Scale performance by ~17%, with minimal changes to Add & Triad performance.  On Ice Lake Xeon, streaming stores *increase* Copy & Scale performance by ~65%, and *increase* Add & Triad performance by ~35%.  Ice Lake Xeon is about 12% faster than Cascade Lake Xeon on each test when using normal allocating stores.  AMD Milan remains much faster than ICX in these single-thread cases -- 1.8x to 2.2x for each category.

Comment: Thanks for that data point on recent hardware.  [Enhanced REP MOVSB for memcpy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43343231) discusses some details of NT (or other no-RFO) vs. regular RFO store protocols, and the difference that can make in bandwidth on server parts.  If you want to repost your comment there, or possibly even post a quick answer with that recent data, that might be a good place to share it.  That Q&A is one I often link as a canonical about RFOs and NT store advantages / disadvantages, so future readers might be likely to find stuff there.